# Pagination in codeigniter doesn't works

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using pagination library of codeigniter, but it doesn't works for me..
Here is my controller

testimonial.php

```html
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class testimonial extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();


         $this->load->model('testimonials_model','obj_testimonials',TRUE);
    }
    
    public function index() {
        $row=0;
        $limit='10';
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url() . '/testimonial/index/';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->obj_testimonials->countrows();
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['testimonials']=$this->obj_testimonials->get_all_entries($row,$lim=1000,$condition=array(),'testimonials_display_order','');
        $this->load->view('web/testimonials',$data);
    }
}
```

My testimonials_model is this

```html
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class testimonials_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'testimonials';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    

    function countrows($condition = array()) {

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        if ($condition) {
            $this->db->where($condition);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $row = $query->num_rows();
        return $row;
    }

    function get_all_entries($row, $limit, $condition = array(), $order_by_fieled, $order_by_type = "asc") {
        //$this->db->where('blog_status','E');
        if ($condition) {
            $this->db->where($condition);
        }
        if ($order_by_fieled) {
            $this->db->order_by($order_by_fieled, $order_by_type);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table, $limit, $row);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }

    

}

?>
```

And my view page is this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= base_url() ?>images/fav.png"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <title>Dream Holidays Cochin</title>
            <link href="<?= base_url() ?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url() ?>fonts/font.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url() ?>css/style_common.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url() ?>css/style5.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url() ?>css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url() ?>js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url() ?>js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        $('.fancybox').fancybox();


                    });
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <!--banner starts here-->
                        <div class="sub-banner-wrapper">
                            <div class="sub-banner"> <img src="<?= base_url() ?>images/sub-banner-3.jpg" /> </div>
                            <div class="transperant-layer">
                                <div class="sub-banner-captions">
                                    <h2>Words fuelling us to <span>serve better!</span></h2>
                                     <p>See comments from our esteemed clients that testifies our excellence, professionalism and commitment. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--banner ends here-->
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="contentarea-main">
                        <div class="content-area-inner">
                            <div class="destination-main">
                                <!--destinations introduction starts here-->
                                <div class="destination-introduction">
                                    <div class="destination-heading">
                                        <h1>Our <span> Testimonials </span></h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="testimonials-page-main">
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php echo $links;?>
                                    </ul>   
                                    <div class="testimonials-box-area">
                                        <?php $i=0;foreach($testimonials as $test){?>
                                        <div class="<?php if($i%2 == 0){echo 'testi-client';}else{echo 'testi-client no-right-margin';}?>">
                                            <?php if(!empty($test['testimonials_image'])){?>
                                            <div class="testi-blue-bg">
                                                <div class="client-round"><img src="<?= base_url()?>uploads/testimonials/thumb/<?= $test['testimonials_image']?>" /></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="client-note">
                                                <p><?= word_limiter($test['testimonials_content'],62);?></p>
                                                <p><span><?= $test['testimonials_name'];?>,</span> <?= $test['testimonials_title'];?></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php }else{?>
                                            <div class="client-note">
                                                <p style="width: 440px;"><?= word_limiter($test['testimonials_content'],62);?></p>
                                                <p><span><?= $test['testimonials_name'];?>,</span> <?= $test['testimonials_title'];?></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php }?>
                                        </div>
                                            
                                        <?php $i++;}?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

While i run this code it displays all the first 10 testimonials but when i click on the pagination link it doesnt works and gaves the same content (first 10 testimonials) itself on the next section of pagination. It counts the number of data and all from database but only first 10 is displayed in all pagination links..

If anyone could help me means it will be very much helpful..

Thank you..

Comment: what is the href of the pagination url? So the url where you go to if you click on page 2 for example.

Comment: Can you show us one of the <a> tags generated by the pagination ?

Comment: where you setup pagination?where is your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination library will help you to create pagination html widget. Retrieving correct data from database according specified page (in the URL) is still developer task.

First you need to retrieve page number from request URL.
Then you need to fix arguments in next line:

```
$data['testimonials']=$this->obj_testimonials->get_all_entries($row,$lim=1000,$condition=array(),'testimonials_display_order','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set index() has the base_url of your pagination.
That means, each links of your pagination will looks like this :

.com/index.php/**controllername**/*page_number*

This can't work because CI will look for a function *page_number()* inside your controller **controllername** which not exists.

Moreover, At the begining of index() you reset  $row=0; $limit='10'; so the query will be always the same.

What you can do is :

1/ Set a new function in your controller. Let's name it page()

```
public function page($page_number) 
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $pagination_config = $this->get_pagination_config();
    $row= $page_number * $per_page - $per_page;
    $limit = $pagination_config["per_page"];

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['testimonials']=$this->obj_testimonials->get_all_entries($row,$lim=10,$condition=array(),'testimonials_display_order','');
    $this->load->view('web/testimonials',$data);
}
```

2/Let's write a function that builds pagination cofig so we will not be doing this multiple time

```
private function getPaginationConfig()
{
    $config['base_url'] = site_url() . '/testimonial/index/page';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->obj_testimonials->countrows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;

    return $config;
}
```

3/ Change index() accordingly

```
public function index() 
{
        $row=0;
        $limit='10';
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = $this->getPaginationConfig();
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['testimonials']=$this->obj_testimonials->get_all_entries($row,$lim=1000,$condition=array(),'testimonials_display_order','');
        $this->load->view('web/testimonials',$data);
}
```

Now your pagination links will be :

.com/index.php/**controllername**/page/*page_number* .
page() will load the good entries according to the *page_number* parameter.

Comment: Thanks alot.. It works fine for me... Have to make some modifications in the code.. Even though it helped me alot.. Thank u verymuch.. :D

Comment: Sorry if the code isn't plug and play, I wrote it directly without testing it. Please make sure to upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check the pagination segment in url and update it to the `$row` in your controller. So that first time it will become `0` and next time it will reset with the pagination limit `$limit='10'`.

```
// URL: 'http://example.com/testimonial/index/10
$row = ! empty($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

That's it.